# Visual Studio 2019 - Missing options for WPF controls in Add Item menu

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a WPF project, and I'm trying to add a User Control to make a reusable component.

Right-clicking the project in the solution explorer, going to the `Add` menu, then clicking UserControl (or New Item, same result), I see this:

[image]

The left menu that says "General", "Uno Platform", ..., does not show "WPF" which I've seen in some videos, and the list in the middle that says "Blank Page", "Class", ..., does not show "User Control".

I thought I had already installed everything I needed for WPF applications given that I'm working on a WPF project in the first place, but perhaps not.

Anything else I need to install for WPF controls (particularly User Control) to be available? I haven't found anything in my vast Googling.

Comment: Run VS installer and check that .NET desktop development is installed

Comment: Ok, that was it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski please post this as solution